# What is probability that $3$ of them of will bear number $1$ to $20$ and fourth will bear any number from $21$ to $100$ .

Tags: probability, combinatorics, proof-verification, permutations, combinations

From $100$ tickets numbered $1,2,3..,100$ four are drawn at random . What is probability that $3$ of them of will bear number $1$ to $20$ and fourth will bear any number from $21$ to $100$ .

My solution : Total number of cases = $100 \choose 4$ . 
Total number of ways selecting 3 numbers from 20 numbers = $20 \choose 3 $ and there are $80$ integers from $21$ and $100$ . So the numbers ways fourth tickets can be drawn is=$80\choose 1$=80 . Hence total number of  favorable cases = ${20 \choose 3} \times 80$ .

So required probability$= \frac {{20 \choose 3} \times 80 }{100 \choose 4}$ .

Is my answer correct . I don't have solution on the book and no way to know if my answer is correct . Thank you .

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.... Your answer is correct!